# Am I creating an Object or a Variable?

Tags: java

I'm reading a book on Java programing and the author uses an example as follows:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat; 
public class NumberFormatTest {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(); 

    }
}
```

I'm confused about this line:

```
NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
```

Is this creating an object of the NumberFormat class, or is this creating a variable?  I realize there's no use of a "new" statement, so I don't think it's an object.  I'm very confused.  Can anyone shed some light on what's going on in this line of code?

Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating `both variable and object`.

```
NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
```

`NumberFormat currency`, creates the `variable` of type NumberFormat.

`NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`, creates the `instance/object` of type NumberFormat and returns the same.

Comment: Technically, @markspace's answer is more correct.  You do not _know_ that `getCurrentyInstance()` is creating anything.  It might be returning a reference to a previously created instance.  In _this_ case, since `NumberFormat` is mutable, it's probably a new instance. In the general case you just don't know without examining the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a variable, and maybe an object.

This line:

```
NumberFormat currency ...
```

creates a local variable.  It would be better to say your declare a local variable, but it isn't wrong to think of this as creating the variable.  The next part:

```
... NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()
```

*might* create an object, but it also might return an object that was created elsewhere in the program (for example, if `getCurrencyInstance()` had already been called elsewhere, it'll likely just reuse the already created object).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are creating an object of the NumberFormat class (or potentially an object of a sub-class of that class). The method you are calling - `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()` - contains the `new` statement which creates the instance. It is a factory method that creates an instance of the class and returns a reference to that instance to the caller.

Your `currency` variable then holds the reference to the `NumberFormat` object.

Comment: Got it...  so the `getCurrencyInstance()` method contains code which includes a `new` statement, which creates the instance, right?

Comment: Correct.  Methods like this typically cache the objects they create, so it'll probably check a static field for null first, then call `new` if the field is null, then return the value (field or new).

Answer (score -1):

You have a variable called "currency" and this is assigned to an Object of type NumberFormat. The only non-object types in java are the primitive types - `int, long, float, boolean` and so on, however there are equivalent objects for each of these.

I expect the confusion is coming from the fact that NumberFormat uses a static method to create its object, so it's doing the `new` for you under the covers.

Your book will probably get to the bit about Objects vs Classes as described here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO